# Json Array Parsing issue in iphone

Tags: iphone

In the following code I parse following web service, but when I parse comments array, it's not consider as array brackets like [] it assumes parenthesis () So I will not parse this array, How it happens Still I didn't get please help me.

Please look at following code snap and please help me.

```
{
    "flag?":false,
    "created_at":"2012-04-29T08:20:04Z",
    "title":"test",
    "user":{
        "name":"abc"
    },
    "comments":[
        {
            "comment":"Hi",
            "created_at":"2012-04-26T07:56:09Z",
            "user":{
                "name":"abc"
            }
        },
        {
            "comment":"hello",
            "created_at":"2012-04-27T07:41:29Z",
            "user":{
                "name":"Mahesh"
            }
        },
        {
            "comment":"good",
            "created_at":"2012-05-01T07:03:02Z",
            "user":{
                "name":"admin"
            }
        }
    ],
    "solution":"test",
    "problem":"test"
}
```

Code snap as follows =: http://pastebin.com/Dg4hjdKA

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443425/xcode-parsing-json-array)

Comment: pastebin url still shows empty page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will help u.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
  [responseData setLength:0];
 }

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
[responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
 [connection release];
 self.responseData = nil;
 }

 - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
  [connection release];


  NSLog(@"Response String= %@",responseString);  //response string is ur  JSON Array value

    NSArray* latestLoans = [(NSDictionary*)[responseString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"comments"];
 NSLog(@"Lateste = %@",latestLoans);

 [responseString release];
 NSDictionary* loan = [latestLoans objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString* number1 = [loan objectForKey:@"comment"];
 NSString* firstName = [loan objectForKey:@"created_at"];
 NSString* emails = [loan objectForKey:@"user"];

 NSLog(@"number1= %@,  firstName= %@  Emails= %@",number1,firstName,emails);
  }
```

Comment: Sorry it's not working..... same o/p gives me

Comment: can u post ur full code in using pastebin.com?

Comment: yes .... I post the code  http://pastebin.com/Dg4hjdKA

Comment: Please give me solution......

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *urlstring = @"Your URL";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstring];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *returnData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *returnString=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",returnString);

SBJSON *json = [SBJSON new];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[json objectWithString:returnString error:nil]];

NSArray *Response_Array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[dict valueForKey:@"comments"]];
```